# XenServer 7.2 parted mkpart error

Tags: linux, partitioning, xen

I am attempting to partition my Dell R710 for VM storage. Details:

1. Newly installed XenServer 7.2. Accepted Defaults.
2. 5x 2TB Drives, Raid 5. Single Virtual Disk. Total storage: 8TB

All I want to do is add two partitions, a 4TB for VM storage, then whatever is left for media storage (~ 3.9TB).

When I run parted to try and create the first partition (4TB), I am receiving an error "Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition." I have Googled and Googled, but am unable to find anything that seems to get me going in the right direction. Additionally, I get a strange message (see the bottom of the screenshot) suggesting I have an issue with my sectors perhaps (34...2047 available?).

Below is a screenshot that contains pertinent information as well as command output. Here's hoping someone can help. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to write a partition to an already partitioned space. You will have to delete the lvm partition first.

Comment: I did that, rebooted, then tried again: (parted) mkpart primary 0GB 4000GB
Warning: You requested a partition from 0.00B to 4000GB (sectors 0..7812500000).
The closest location we can manage is 17.4kB to 1048kB (sectors 34..2047).
Still getting odd sector notice

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up booting from a Debian live cd and using gparted to tweak the partition size. This worked like a charm. Marking meatball's answer as correct as this was what lead me down this path.